# Can't get my domain working. What should I do?

Tags: dns, vps

Soo we bough a domain name with the name of mastergamingteam.eu and we've been trying to make it work, but it does not seem to. I've tried a lot of stuff online, but we still can't connect to the page.

From client side it says DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

We use ubuntu 16.04.6

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName mastergamingteam.eu
ServerAlias www.mastergamingteam.eu
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/etc/hosts(This keeps getting overwritten, this is there by default):

```
# Generated by SolusVM
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain
79.139.56.118   mastergamingteam
```

Port 80 is enabled by ufw and Listened in apache2

A Record:
mastergamingteam.eu priority:0  TTL:7200    Type:A  Value:79.139.56.118

NS Record:
mastergamingteam.eu priority:0  TTL:86400   Type:NS Value:ns1.rackforest.hu

The VPS is hosted by rackforest and bought the domain on their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain record at registrar has errors in name servers' hostnames.

```
$whois mastergamingteam.eu
Domain: mastergamingteam.eu
...
Registrar:
        Name: PDR Ltd.
        Website: https://www.publicdomainregistry.com

Name servers:
        sn1.rackforest.hu
        sns1.racforest.hu
```

You should edit record registrar and put **ns1**.rackforest.hu as the first name server.

Also there is only one NS record for your domain.

```
 $ host -t ns  mastergamingteam.eu ns1.rackforest.hu
    Using domain server:
    Name: ns1.rackforest.hu
    Address: 185.43.204.2#53
    Aliases: 
    
    mastergamingteam.eu name server ns1.rackforest.hu
```

You should probably have ns2.rackforest.hu as second name server.

ns2.rackforest.hu knows about your domain.

```
$host  mastergamingteam.eu ns2.rackforest.hu
Using domain server:
Name: ns2.rackforest.hu
Address: 79.172.213.19#53
Aliases: 

mastergamingteam.eu has address 79.139.56.118
```

Comment: I think I did it, even the link given by the other commenter works, but still can't connect and gives the same error output on the client side.

Comment: I think I just had to wait some hours. Now it works, really appreciate it! <3

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is:

your domain points nowhere. There are no records for your domain (no A or CNAME or any other relevant records) neither are any nameservers configured.

Make sure to set records, as obviously the domain won't work.

You can check your domain's records yourself here: https://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=mastergamingteam.eu&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=

Comment: If I specify myself the nameserver like this:
https://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=mastergamingteam.eu&type=&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=ns1.rackforest.hu

Then it finds it. So should I create a nameserver record with another server(which one if this is the case?) or does this mean that the domain is only available on this nameserver, means most of the people can't connect, only by manual settings?